# Grouping and summing two columns using awk

Tags: awk

How do I get Region-wise totals of Sales and Cost from the data below?

```
Region Sales Cost
North 139 35
South 786 295
South 312 117
East 288 108
North 149 56
West 508 127
North 145 54
South 379 142
East 500 188
```

eg.

```
North 433 145
and so on
```

Comment: I have worked with one associative array eg. {a[$1]+=$2 and later print out the array in the END statement. It gives sum of column 2. Not sure how to do it for two columns simultaneously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Simple*!, just use two arrays.

```
awk 'NR>1{uniqueSales[$1]+=$2; uniqueCost[$1]+=$3; next}
END{for (i in uniqueSales) print i,uniqueSales[i],uniqueCost[i]}' file
```

The code works by skipping the first record `NR>1`, where `NR` is a special variable keeping track of the line numbers of each line `Awk` is processing. Then we create a *hash-map* with index being `$1` and two different arrays `uniqueSales[$1]+=$2; uniqueCost[$1]+=$3` that increment the values from `$2` and `$3` respectively.

Once all the lines are processed. The `END` clause prints the values from both the arrays to get the required output needed.

```
South 1477 554
East 788 296
North 433 145
West 508 127
```

Comment: Thanks both for the solution and the explanation!